# How should I go about solving this recursion without trial and error

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

```
int sum_down(int x)
{
    if (x >= 0)
    {
        x = x - 1;
        int y = x + sum_down(x);
        return y + sum_down(x);
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

What is this smallest integer value of the parameter x, so that the returned value is greater than 1.000.000 ?

Right now I am just doing it by trial and error and since this question is asked via a paper format. I don't think I will have enough time to do trial and error. Question is, how do you guys visualise this quickly such that it can be solved easily. Thanks guys and I am new to programming so thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer is 19. And, to me, the question should be asked to [Maths Stack](http://maths.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: I don't really get this question. And I don't understand the upvotes...Is this a math question how to solve recurrences? Do you simply want the answer? Do you want to know how somebody else would approach it? Personally I would wrap this in a loop and break when the result is >1'000'000.

Comment: I would first get rid of the mutation: `if (x >= 0) { return x - 1 + 2 * sum_down(x - 1); }`.

Comment: Hi i'm not looking for the answer. I just need help figuring out how to solve these sort of questions like the directions I should take. But thanks guys. :)

Comment: Is this from a class? Are you studying recurrence relations?

Comment: You also can have a look at **Chapter 5 : Recursion** of Discrete Mathematics with Applications by Thomas Koshy for better understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recursion logic:

```
x = x - 1;
int y = x + sum_down(x);
return y + sum_down(x);
```

can be simplified to:

```
x = x - 1;
int y = x + sum_down(x) + sum_down(x);
return y;
```

which can be simplified to:

```
int y = (x-1) + sum_down(x-1) + sum_down(x-1);
return y;
```

which can be simplified to:

```
return (x-1) + 2*sum_down(x-1);
```

Put in mathematical form,

```
f(N) = (N-1) + 2*f(N-1)
```

with the recursion terminating when `N` is `-1`. `f(-1)` = `1`.

Hence,

```
f(0) = -1 + 2*1 = 1
f(1) =  0 + 2*1 = 2
f(2) =  1 + 2*2 = 5

...

f(18) = 17 + 2*f(17) = 524269
f(19) = 18 + 2*524269 = 1048556
```

Comment: Woah thanks for that ! It seems so easy when you explain it. How did you find the terminating condition ?

Comment: @Blake_Lead, the terminating condition is in the `else` part of the function.

Answer (score 4):

Your program can be written this way (sorry about c#):

```
public static void Main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    do
    {
        i++;
        j = sum_down(i);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("j:" + j);
    } while (j < 1000000);
    Console.Out.WriteLine("i:" + i);
}
static int sum_down(int x)
{
    if (x >= 0)
    {
        return x - 1 + 2 * sum_down(x - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

So at first iteration you'll get 2, then 5, then 12... So you can neglect the x-1 part since it'll stay little compared to the multiplication.

So we have:

```
i = 1 => sum_down ~= 4 (real is 2)
i = 2 => sum_down ~= 8 (real is 5)
i = 3 => sum_down ~= 16 (real is 12)
i = 4 => sum_down ~= 32 (real is 27)
i = 5 => sum_down ~= 64 (real is 58)
```

So we can say that sum_down(x) ~= 2^<sup>x+1</sup>. Then it's just basic math with 2^<sup>x+1</sup> < 1 000 000 which is 19.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense! Thanks!

Comment: It is a great answer. And thanks for the little math explanation, I could not find a way to put it that way.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but it's not that hard to get an exact non-recursive formula.

Write it up mathematically, as explained in other answers already:

```
f(-1) = 1
f(x) = 2*f(x-1) + x-1
```

This is the same as

```
f(-1) = 1
f(x+1) = 2*f(x) + x
```

(just switched from x and x-1 to x+1 and x, difference 1 in both cases)

The first few x and f(x) are:

```
x:    -1  0  1  2  3  4
f(x): 1   1  2  5  12 27
```

And while there are many arbitrary complicated ways to transform this into a non-recursive formula, with easy ones it often helps to write up what the difference is between each two elements:

```
x:    -1  0  1  2  3  4  
f(x): 1   1  2  5  12 27  
        0  1  3  7  15
```

So, for some x

```
f(x+1) - f(x) = 2^(x+1) - 1  
f(x+2) - f(x) = (f(x+2) - f(x+1)) + (f(x+1) - f(x)) = 2^(x+2) + 2^(x+1) - 2  
f(x+n) - f(x) = sum[0<=i<n](2^(x+1+i)) - n
```

With eg. a `x=0` inserted, to make `f(x+n)` to `f(n)`:

```
f(x+n) - f(x) = sum[0<=i<n](2^(x+1+i)) - n  
f(0+n) - f(0) = sum[0<=i<n](2^(0+1+i)) - n  
f(n) - 1 = sum[0<=i<n](2^(i+1)) - n   
f(n) = sum[0<=i<n](2^(i+1)) - n + 1   
f(n) = sum[0<i<=n](2^i) - n + 1   
f(n) = (2^(n+1) - 2) - n + 1
f(n) = 2^(n+1) - n - 1
```

No recursion anymore.

Answer (score 1):

How about this :

```
int x = 0;
while (sum_down(x) <= 1000000)
{
    x++;
}
```

The loop increments x until the result of sum_down(x) is superior to 1.000.000.

Edit : The result would be 19.

While trying to understand and simplify the recursion logic behind the `sum_down()` function is enlightening and informative, this snippet tend to be logical and pragmatic in that it does not try and solve the problem in terms of context, but in terms of results.

Comment: @Blake_Lead, your logic is faulty. You are checking the result after `x` has been incremented.

Comment: There you go mate.. I removed my downvote and my rude comment. Sorry for that.... I still won't upvote it though...

Comment: Hi, how do you guys figuring out if it's 20. I'm not looking for the answer but rather the direction or logic i should apply to these sort of questions. Cause right now all I am doing is by trial and error and I know that it is not the most ideal way for solving these sort of questions.. Many thanks guys!

Comment: It is looking better...if you now remove the `res` variable it will be even more readable. `while(sum_down(x)<=1000000){x++;}`

Comment: Sorry for being rude first. The thing was that in the beginning this answer was looking as if it didn't have any effort and/or thought put into it... But yes, you are completely right, my tone was inappropriate... sorry again... If you want to further improve your answer, I suggest you mention that this is a *pragmatic approach* to the problem, even when the recurrence is not as simple to solve as in this case. I.e. it is a generalized approach - the other answers are not and will fail as soon as the recurrence gets too complicated... If you do that I'll upvote.. cheers!.

Comment: I understand your position. I did make an effort in thinking and trying the code myself and my lack of knowledge hid the errors. But my position is to answer anyway for many reasons : I get to work on the problem, and to code a solution. I often have to do some research and I interact with experienced developers which I am not (neither experienced nor developper)

Comment: I upvoted.. unfortunately somebody else downvoted it.. that's why you have 0

Comment: I know thanks :). This answer does not deserve more anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Two lines of Python code to answer your question:

```
>>> from itertools import *   # no code but needed for dropwhile() and count()
```

Define the recursive function (See R Sahu's answer)

```
>>> f = lambda x: 1 if x<0 else (x-1) + 2*f(x-1)
```

Then use the `dropwhile()` function to remove elements from the list [0, 1, 2, 3, ....] for which `f(x)<=1000000`, resulting in a list of integers for which `f(x) > 1000000`. Note: `count()` returns an infinite "list" of [0, 1, 2, ....]

The `dropwhile()` function returns a Python generator so we use `next()` to get the first value of the list:

```
>>> next(dropwhile(lambda x: f(x)<=1000000, count()))
19
```