# Rewriting a recursive function to a non-recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

```
int foo(int x)
{   
    if (x >= 0)
    {
        return (x - 1) + 2 * foo(x - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Hi, I need to rewrite this function such that it will be free of recursion. I tried solving this mathematically, but to no avail. I am new to programming, so any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what precisely did you try? Are you sure it's not `if(x > 0)`?

Comment: Consider: `f(0)=1` and `f(n)=(n-1) + 2*f(n-1)`. If we know the value of `n-1`, we know the value of `n`. Could this be written as a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that it really should be `if(x>0)` in your question.

Then examining your function, we see that `foo(0)=1` and otherwise that `foo(x)=(x-1)+2*foo(x-1)`. Thus `foo(x)` only depends on `foo(x-1)`. So, you can simply use an iteration to progress the result

```
int foo(int x)
{
  auto result=1;           // result if x=0
  for(int n=0; n!=x; ++n)  // increment result to desired x
    result=n+2*result;     // corresponds to (x-1)+2*foo(x-1) in original
  return result;
}
```

If it really was `if(x>=0)` instead, I leave it as an exercise to you to adapt the code.

Comment: There was a related question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096018/how-should-i-go-about-solving-this-recursion-without-trial-and-error. It appears that `if ( x >= 0 )` is right. `foo(-1) = 1`. It so happens that `foo(0) = 1` too.

Comment: @Walter Thanks for your help. In the question, its `if ( x >= 0)` Is there any way to make it adapt to it? Yes @Sahu, it is a related question as per the link you posted.

Comment: @Alan1 I think you received a lot of help and hints and you should be able to work that out for yourself. Think of what the result for `x=-1` will be and start the loop from there. Always check that your recursive and non-recursive functions obtain the same answers.

Comment: @Walter, thanks I have managed to work that out myself. Thank you so much for you help!